# How do I hide notice error for a specific variable?

Tags: php, php-7

I have an optional variable in a class:

```
private $port = DB_PORT; // The port number where the MySQL is listening.
```

If the user doesn't specify doesn't defined the variable , php would throw a notice:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PORT - assumed 'DB_PORT'
```

How can i modify my **code** to tell PHP to ignore any error from that variable?

Comment: You can use `@` before your variable.

Comment: Instead of ignoring errors, why don't you simply use proper coding techniques that will never allow for such errors in the first place?

Comment: @N.B I am all ears...feel free to elaborate

Comment: Perhaps a random idea, but how about defining the constant...

Comment: Step #1 - post your **actual** code. Step #2 - explain what you want to happen and what actually happens. In step #3, guys from SO will jump in and tell you how to achieve the desired goal. I'm going to make an educated guess here - you're coming up with some sort of PDO wrapper here. Instead of directly accessing **variables** (members), use methods that will retrieve values of those variables, and if those values aren't set - return a custom-defined value.

Comment: something like `private $port = defined('DB_PORT') ? DB_PORT : null ;`?

Comment: @N.B. The code is on github --> https://github.com/khavishbhundoo/mysql-pdo-class/blob/master/database.class.php .

Comment: @Sean Great....somehow i didn't think about it :(

Comment: @Sean Unfortunately it does work in PHP 7 `Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) function to handle the various cases you have to face.

```
if (!defined('DB_PORT')) throw ew MyException("DB_PORT must be configured");
```